# How do I detect small blobs using EmguCV?

Tags: opencv, tracking, emgucv, blobs

I'm trying to track the position of a robot from an overhead webcam. However, as I don't have much access to the robot or the environment, so I have been working with snapshots from the webcam.
The robot has 5 bright LEDs positioned strategically which are a different enough color from the robot and the environment so as to easily isolate.
I have been able to do just that using EmguCV, resulting in a binary image like the one below. My question is now, how to I get the positions of the five blobs and use those positions to determine the position and orientation of the robot?

[image]

I have been experimenting with the `Emgu.CV.VideoSurveillance.BlobTrackerAuto` class, but it stubbornly refuses to detect the blobs in the above image. Being a bit of a newbie when it comes to any of this, I'm not sure what I could be doing wrong.
So what would be the best method of obtaining the positions of the blobs in the above image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't tell you how to do it with emgucv in particular, you'd need to translate the calls from opencv to emgucv. You'd use [cv::findContours](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/imgproc_structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#cv-findcontours) to get the blobs and [cv::moments](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/imgproc_structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#cv-moments) to get the position of the blobs (the formula to get the middle points of the blobs is in the documentation of `cv::moments`). Then you'd use [cv::estimateRigidTransform](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/imgproc_structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#cv-estimaterigidtransform) to get the position and orientation of the robot.

Comment: This has helped me a lot, thanks.  
Unfortunately, I can't seem to find an emguCV analogue to estimateRigidTransform, and have no idea how to call it... I'll keep looking, but so far you've helped me heaps.

Comment: @death_au: Shouldn't be too hard to do it yourself to get position&orientation when you have the 5 positions. Identify the middle point in the line that has 3 points, use the mean from the other 4 points as position and the direction from the mean to the 5th point as orientation.

Comment: @death_au: It's `CvInvoke.cvEstimateRigidTransform();` in Emgu

Answer (score 0):

I use cvBlob library to work blobs. Yesterday i worked with it to detect small blobs and works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a python module to do this very thing.

http://letsmakerobots.com/node/38883#comments